# Can I obtain the permutation importance for xgboost and lightgbm in Learning api?

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, lightgbm

I want to get the permutaion importance of xgboost and lightgbm model provided by [learning api](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.training). I can find many examples to get the permutation importance in [sklearn api](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn) using `permutation_importance` from `sklearn.inspection` or  `PermutationImportance` from `eli5.sklearn` but I could not find the way in learning api.